# How to extract the return type of a controller method using reflection

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, system.reflection

In .Net 6

I have a controller with the following method signature

`public async Task<ActionResult<MyClass>> Method() {...}`

Using reflection, how do I extract the type (MyClass in this example)?

I tried using the Type.GetGenericType method but it doesn't work

Thank you

Comment: where do you want to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ReturnType` and `GetGenericArguments` to  extract the type.

```
//......
var methodinfo =  t.GetMethod("Method");
var result = methodinfo.ReturnType;
var resultType =  result.GetGenericArguments()[0].GetGenericArguments();
```

Now the `resultType` is what you want to get.